# What is it like to call/text on 2 of 5 bands of 4G

Tags: xiaomi, verizon

The phone I want (Xiaomi Pocophone F1) is only compatible with 1 Verizon band. I was wondering what it's like to call/text like this? Even if it's low quality, but I could still understand the person and speak to them and they understand me, that's all I need. EDIT/ANSWER: If a phone is only compatible with a certain network with not all the bands, you can look at a cellular map to see what bands of that provider are emitting from the towers in your area, for me, the bands that did work with my provider and my phone DID NOT work in my area, so it depends on area, and if you travel very big chance you won't have any service unless it is the most popular band used by the provider.

Comment: I would expect that the coverage area of that band would be important as well. Perhaps not all Verizon towers utilize that particular band and you could be without service in an area that is covered by Verizon on another band(s).

Comment: Oh I will check on that. Do you know how it would be if the band was in my area?

Comment: If your area's Verizon uses the band that's present on the phone, then it should work just fine. Else the phone should drop down to 3G or 2G for service.

Comment: Ok thank you I will look into this more and see if I can use this phone in my area.

Comment: Oh thanks for the help but the Huawei Honor Play and Pocophone F1 won't work in my area, you know of any other flapship killer type phones about ~$300?

Comment: We don't do phone recommendations here, only factual questions, but now that you've worked out the answer to your question, could you post an answer to help out other visitors please?

Comment: Will do. I am going to write an answer now.